# NodeJs No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I am trying to access an rss feed using an Ajax request on the client broswer.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=uk',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(responseData)
},
error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('failed.');
}
});
```

This is giving me the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

I have installed the cors package so it should be enabled on my server, am i missing something?

server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors()); 

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//    res.send('Hello World');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
})

var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', routes);


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Edit* Full error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=uk. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Wait - you are querying http://feeds.bbci.co.uk which misses the appropriate CORS headers. You then would need to reconfigure the BBC server to include CORS headers, not your own...?

Comment: Yes i am querying the bbc web domain and not my node js server. The error say localhost that is why am confused that it might be my end?
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081'

Comment: The `origin` header is sent by your client to the BBC server. The requested resource however is the BBC server, which doesn't reply with the necessary CORS headers.

Comment: Origin: localhost:8081 just means that's the domain the cross origin resource was requested from. This question is strange to me though, localhost:8081 is accepted for me without CORS issues. Are you sure it's this specific request that is failing?

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure. It has me really confused. I may try get the rss feed directly from my server. So the client will call an endpoint on my node server then make the request to the BBC RSS feed. Was hoping i didnt have to route the data through my server though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=uk` doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, you need to instead make the request through proxy. Do that by changing the value of `url` in your frontend JavaScript code like this:

```
url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/business/rss.xml?edition=uk',
```

The `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/…` URL will cause the request to go to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`, a open/public CORS proxy which then sends the request on to the `http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/…` URL you actually want to request.

And when that proxy gets the response, it’ll take it and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then pass that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees, so the error message the browser is showing you now goes away, and the browser allows your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

Or use the code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ or such to set up your own proxy.

The reason you need a proxy is that, because `http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/…` itself doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, your browser will refuse to let your frontend JavaScript code access a response from that server cross-origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com over routing through my own webserver? My thought was to make the request from the client instead of my server to save on extra data processing

Comment: The only advantage of using a public proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ is that it doesn’t require you to set up anything yourself on your backend—instead you can just replace whatever URL you’re requesting with a URL for the proxy. Of course it’s fine to instead if write a proxy of your own or otherwise write the handling into your own backend.